# Batch Syntax For Loop If Exists

Tags: syntax, if-statement, batch-file, for-loop

Trying to create a batch to convert .WTV files to mpg files. The code below I want to run once a night to convert the daily recordings for use on my media server. The section I am concerned about syntax is the for loop line. I only want to run the script on the files that have not been converted and moved. I cant delete the original in case and error occurs. The last move loop is to get all the files it couldn't move on the first try.

the input files look like : show.wtv

the output in the file is show.wtv.mpg (which I'm ok with)

I am not sure how to write that for loop to get the desired functionality. Any help is appreciated.

Original idea came from http://ireckon.net/2009/10/converting-wtv-to-mpg-in-windows-7/

```
@echo off

set recordedtv="D:\Recorded TV\"
set destfolder="D:\Videos\Recorded TV\"
set ffmpeg="D:\TV Converter\FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe"
set wtvconv="C:\Windows\ehome\WTVConverter.exe"

for %%f in (%recordedtv%*.wtv) Do If Not Exist "%destfolder%%%f.mpg" (
%wtvconv% "%%f" "%%f.dvr-ms"
%ffmpeg% -y -i "%%f.dvr-ms" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f dvd "%%f.mpg"
del "%%f.dvr-ms"
move "%%f.mpg" %destfolder%
)

for %%f in (%recordedtv%*.mpg) Do move "%%f" %destfolder%
```

UPDATE: Ended up using this

```
@echo off

set "recordedtv=D:\Recorded TV\"
set "destfolder=D:\Videos\Recorded TV\"
set ffmpeg="D:\TV Converter\FFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe"
set wtvconv="C:\Windows\ehome\WTVConverter.exe"

for %%f in ("%recordedtv%*.wtv") do If Not Exist "%destfolder%%%~nxf.mpg" (
%wtvconv% "%%f" "%%f.dvr-ms"
%ffmpeg% -y -i "%%f.dvr-ms" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f dvd "%%f.mpg"
del "%%f.dvr-ms"
move "%%f.mpg" "%destfolder%"
)

for %%f in ("%recordedtv%*.mpg") Do move "%%f" "%destfolder%"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to add other parts to paths stored in variables, do not store the paths with the surrounding quotation marks. Just leave the double quotes out or put them like this:

```
...
set "recordedtv=D:\Recorded TV\"
set "destfolder=D:\Videos\Recorded TV\"
...
```

That way you'll be able to concatenate the paths with names/masks without causing syntax errors. Note that your paths are not delimited with double quotes, so you'll need to delimit them where they are evaluated, as necessary, so, for instance, the `for` loops would look like this:

```
for %%f in ("%recordedtv%*.wtv") do ...
...
for %%f in ("%recordedtv%*.mpg") do ...
```

Pay attention to other places as well. For example, in the `move` command in your script the target path will also have to be delimited:

```
move "%%f.mpg" "%destfolder%"
```

As for file existance check, that is done with the `if exist` command:

```
if exist target_file (
...    // do whatever you need to do in case the file exists
)
```

The *`target_file`* bit can be a file, a mask, or a directory (in the latter case it should end with `\`).

**UPDATE**

I think I can see now a particular problem with your script. This part

```
for %%f in (%recordedtv%*.wtv) Do If Not Exist "%destfolder%%%f.mpg"
```

is wrong in that it puts your destination folder and the full path to a `.wtv` file together and uses the resulting string as a single path. So `"%destfolder%%%f"` gets evaluated to something like this:

```
"D:\Videos\Recorded TV\D:\Recorded TV\somename.wtv.mpg"
```

I'm only not sure about extra quotation marks, but that is not the point here. I guess you can see the main problem. To resolve it, you need to extract only file name and extension from `D:\Recorded TV\somename.wtv.mpg`, which is done using the combined `~nx` specifier (`n` standing for ‘name’ and `x` for ‘extension’):

```
for %%f in ("%recordedtv%*.wtv") Do If Not Exist "%destfolder%%%~nxf.mpg"
```

(Note that the folder paths should still be stored without surrounding double quotes in order for them to be evaluated correctly in complex expressions.)

Comment: thanks for all the tips but this doesn't help the overall problem.

Comment: @GRush: What *is* the overall problem?

Comment: for %%f in (%recordedtv%*.wtv) Do If Not Exist "%destfolder%%%f.mpg" (
I did some messing around to get the if not exist to work and I was unsuccessful.

Comment: @GRush: I think I've got it now, please see my update and let me know if there are still issues not addressed.

Comment: Extra quotes within a file path do not cause a problem. This path is perfectly legal and will not generate a syntax error: `"D:\Recorded TV\""myFile.mpg"`. That being said, I like to avoid the extra quotes if possible.